# jqGrid Custom call editable modal form

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.9.3-pre - free
This example ok-soft-gmbh.com (Oleg):

[demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ViewFormOnDoubleClick1.htm)

But I put in my code line:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid("viewGridRow", rowid, { caption: "Details of the invice" });
}
```

The modal window with each new challenge is moving down.
I found a line where changes:

```
        if (!o.recreateForm) {
            var formProp = $self.data("formProp");
            console.log(formProp)
            if (formProp) {
                formProp.top = Math.max(formProp.top, 0);
                formProp.left = Math.max(formProp.left, 0);
                $.extend(o, formProp);
            }
        }
```

With each call a modal window increasing `formProp.top` and `formProp.left`.

How fix this problem?

For Oleg: Добрый день! Мне нужно вызывать viewGridRow и editGridRow кастомно. Тут по большей части только вы можете помочь. У меня при вызове модального окна, с каждым вызовом увеличиватся top and left.Пример своего кода не привожу. Но если нужно напишу.

Comment: Добрый день! Could you include the demo, which reproduce the problem? I can't reproduce and changing of position of `top` and `left` on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ViewFormOnDoubleClick1.htm).

Comment: я пока могу свой код написать:

Comment: I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/tzp91wnf/ which reproduces the problem. I will examine it and post the bug fix with my answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! I posted [the bug fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/3e9c487dd5564fc99081d8ad2c90a913862439a8) just now. It modified the code of internal `savePositionOnHide` function used for saving the previously position from

```js
savePositionOnHide = function (propName, frmgr, h) {
    var $w = h.w, $form = $(frmgr), $gbox = this.closest(".ui-jqgrid"), top, left;
    if ($.contains($gbox[0], $w[0])) {
        // we use below .style.height and .style.width to save correctly "auto" and "100%" values
        // the "px" suffix will be saved too, but it's not a problem
        top = getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "top");
        left = getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "left");
    } else {
        top = $w.offset().top -
                ($gbox.offsetParent().offset().top +
                $gbox.offset().top +
                $gbox.position().top +
                parseFloat($gbox.css("border-top-width") || 0));
        left = $w.offset().left -
                ($gbox.offsetParent().offset().left +
                $gbox.offset().left +
                $gbox.position().left +
                parseFloat($gbox.css("border-left-width") || 0));
    }
    this.data(propName, {
        top: top,                 //parseFloat($w.css("top")),
        left: left,               //parseFloat($w.css("left")),
        width: getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "width"),             //$(h.w).width(),
        height: getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "height"),           //$(h.w).height(),
        dataheight: getCssStyleOrFloat($form, "height") || "auto",
        datawidth: getCssStyleOrFloat($form, "width") || "auto"
    });
    $w.remove();
    if (h.o) { h.o.remove(); }
}
```

to

```js
savePositionOnHide = function (propName, frmgr, h) {
    var $w = h.w, $form = $(frmgr), $gbox = this.closest(".ui-jqgrid"),
        getTopOrLeftRelativeToGbox = function (topOrLeft) {
            return $w.offset()[topOrLeft] -
                ($gbox.offsetParent().offset()[topOrLeft] +
                $gbox.offset()[topOrLeft] +
                $gbox.position()[topOrLeft] +
                parseFloat($gbox.css("border-" + topOrLeft + "-width") || 0));
        };
    this.data(propName, {
        top: getTopOrLeftRelativeToGbox("top"),
        left: getTopOrLeftRelativeToGbox("left"),
        width: getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "width"),
        height: getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "height"),
        dataheight: getCssStyleOrFloat($form, "height") || "auto",
        datawidth: getCssStyleOrFloat($form, "width") || "auto"
    });
    $w.remove();
    if (h.o) { h.o.remove(); }
},
```

I hope that the problem is fixed in case of all combinations of the input parameters of form editing. At least the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/tzp91wnf/ works now correctly.